# How to handle binding variable in firebase+angular?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have one problem about related to angualrFire and Firebase.

Please see this picture about what I want
[image]

Now, user1 chat with user4. and there are several users in each user list (on the left side)

If user4 click on user1, they both can chat together(the chat box will appear on the right side). In this case, I have binding `messageDetail`variable with `Firebase`

My problem is, when user4 click on user2, `messageDetail`will change and this changing will broadcast to user1 screen (because `messageDetail` is binding with `Firebase`)

1. Initialize Firebase & binding

```js
$scope.initFirebase = function (obj) {
  ref = firebase.database().ref().child('message').child(obj.unique_id);
  // download the data into a local object
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  // synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "messageDetail").then(function (unbind,data) {});
}
```

Please kindly help and guide me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi all, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you share the code on how you compose and save each conversation (messageDetail)? You need to have separate messageDetail for chats between user1&user4 and when user4 starts a new chat with user2, user1 is not part of that chat and should not see the messageDetail between user 2 and 4. You may also want to share your data model to help with the answer.

Comment: Check out the tutorial at https://thinkster.io/angularfire-slack-tutorial